# Using present continuous for describing what we have done in an article

Tags: present-continuous

I wrote:

> Before presenting a method to extract the image of a grate from the video frames, let us formulate the problem. Since **we are tracking** a sequence of frames, we include *t* parameter as the frame number. Then, the *b[t](x, y)* indicates the binary value of the pixel located at *(x, y)* position in the frame *t*.

I used present continues, to imply a nature of the problem which is tracking a sequence of frames. Am I right at this?

Comment: included or include ?

Comment: @Cardinal include or have included?!

Comment: I think progressive tens is not suitable here in this context.I would say **Since we aim to  track the X, we put forward t as the frame number**.

Comment: Moreover, I think either past or present perfect with present progressive sounds awkward. I don't know. I am eager to see the mater's comments

Answer (score 3):

Without more context it's impossible to say whether you should use the simple present or present perfect in this particular instance; but I can provide a general principle.

Your opening provides a present-tense discourse context:

> Since we *are tracking* a sequence ...

You have thus cast your discourse as a present-tense narrative, so the reader will expect you to describe your activities in sequence, step-by-step, like a sportscaster. Activities which you name as you perform them should be cast in the simple present; so if you are introducing the parameter *t* into a formula which you are in the process of building you should narrate that with a simple present:

> Since we are tracking a sequence of frames, we first **include** a parameter *t* and **set** it to our initial frame number. Next ...

If, however, you are starting from a previously given formula—if the formula is so to speak the 'background' for your narrative, you may call attention to the already defined parameter *t* with a present perfect:

> Note that since we are tracking a sequence of frames we **have included** a parameter *t* which holds the current frame number, and **have set** it to the number of our initial frame. Now ...

Comment: Thank you, I provided more context, I actually go to present a formula. What is your suggestion for that?

Comment: @Ahmad Probably the simplest thing is to say "Since ..., our formula includes a parameter *t* ..." and go on from there.